# PKIX path building failed, but I am accepting all cipher suites

Tags: java, bouncycastle, okhttp

I am trying to make an Http Connection with OkHttp 3
I have:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 2);
ConnectionSpec spec = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS)
                    .allEnabledTlsVersions()
                    .allEnabledCipherSuites()
                    .build();
            clientBuilder.connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec));
        }
OkHttpClient httpClient = clientBuilder.readTimeout(360, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

Response response = httpClient.newCall(builder.build()).execute();
```

This seems to work, but occasionally I get this

```
SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Is there some way I can fix this?

Comment: Ciphersuites and certificate validation (including path building) are almost completely unrelated; your Q is like: my car has no wheels and doesn't drive properly even when I fill the gas tank. The way to fix a cert path problem starts by looking at the cert path (and your truststore if nonstandard) about which you give no information at all. There are lots of approaches; for j7+ easiest may be `keytool -printcert -sslserver $servername[:port]`

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 is there a way to add these programatically ? I will be running this in AWS and do not have access to their JVM.